# c:forEach is unable to display the list returned by controller class

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

Output:
[image: output Image]
I am getting this output when I run the following code. I guess that the problem is with `c:forEach`. Could anyone please help me what I did wrong?

Method in Controller Class:

```
@RequestMapping("/viewemp")    
public ModelAndView viewemp() {  
    List<Emp> listOfEmps=dao.getEmployees();
    /*for(int i = 0; i < listOfEmps.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(listOfEmps.get(i).getEmpno());
    }*/
    return new ModelAndView("viewemp","list",listOfEmps);  
}
```

Jsp Page:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>    
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>    

<h1>Employees List</h1>  
<table border="2" width="70%" cellpadding="2">  
<tr><th>Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Salary</th><th>Designation</th><th>Edit</th><th>Delete</th></tr>  
   <c:forEach var="emp" items="${list}">   
   <tr>  
   <td>${emp.empno}</td>  
   <td>${emp.ename}</td>  
   <td>${emp.sal}</td>  
   <td>${emp.job}</td>  
   <td><a href="editemp/${emp.empno}">Edit</a></td>  
   <td><a href="deleteemp/${emp.empno}">Delete</a></td>  
   </tr>  
   </c:forEach>  
   </table>
```

Comment: Check if `listOfEmps` is NULL or not.

Comment: I have checked using following code:
for(int i = 0; i < listOfEmps.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(listOfEmps.get(i).getEmpno());
    }

I am getting all the values

Comment: There is nobody interpreting your page. The `<c:forEach` is simply ignored, the `${...}` expressions printed as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to jstl.

1. Have you included jstl in your lib's ?!
2. In your jsp do you have the following declaration

   `<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" isELIgnored="false"%>`

Answer (score 0):

u need to use the same variable what u have used in the controller to get the values from controller to the jsp page in this case its viewemp , so try using that variable , it might work

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the instance variables used in your model classes are same as you are using in jsp forEach loop. Like in emp.empno, check whether empno exists in model class or not.

Answer (score 0):

Issue can be due to JSTL libraries. If using maven, add dependency for JSTL from following link.

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jstl/jstl/1.2